# query dynamodb with BETWEEN ComparisonOperator

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

In DynamoDB I would like to make a query using the `BETWEEN` ComparisonOperator, but I am getting stuck on the syntax.

From what I could find this should be how it is done:

```
$iterator = $client->query(array(
  'TableName' => 'test',
  'IndexName' => 'lft-index',
  'KeyConditions' => array(
    'lft' => array(
      'AttributeValueList' => array(
        array(
          'N' => 15
        ),
        array(
            'N' => 18),
      ),
      'ComparisonOperator' => 'BETWEEN',
    ),
  ),
));
```

With this code, I get the error message: AWS Error Message: Query key condition not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** use BETWEEN operator for Hash keys as of now, I am assuming 'lft' is your hash key.

When you query DynamoDB you have to pass Hash key with Equality operator only. You can optionally pass Range key with other operators.

Refer this [link.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Query)