# With AWS DocumentClient less than on secondary index query - "Query key condition not supported"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

The function below, it should be simple, right? This is what I thought as well. Still, for the life of me, I cannot figure out why I keep getting an error informing me of a, "`ValidationException`," with an error informing me, "`Query key condition not supported`."

```
const getUpdated = (refreshDatetime, callback) => {

  refreshDatetime = parseInt(refreshDatetime);

  docClient.query({
    TableName: 'aw-reach',
    IndexName: 'updateDatetime-index',
    KeyConditionExpression: ':refreshDatetime < updateDatetime',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':refreshDatetime': refreshDatetime,
    }
  }, (error, data) => {
    if (error) callback(error, null);
    callback(null, data.Items);
  });
};
```

Just to make sure I am not doing anything else incredibly stupid (a distinct possibility as well), here is the snippet I am using to test.

```
const refreshDatetime = Date.parse('01 Jan 2015');
getUpdated(refreshDatetime, (error, response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

Insight and ideas are welcomed and greatly appreciated as writing code, even this little code, definitely is not my strongest talent!

Update: To add additional detail, my hash key is `reachId`, and my partition key associated with my secondary index is `updateDatetime`.

[image]

Comment: is refreshDatetime your hash key?

Comment: It is the partition key associated with the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamodb does not allow to use any other condition except "=" on Hash/partition key.

You can optionally use other expressions for Range/sort key but not for Hash key.

refer: [Documentation link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Query)

[Another post with similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40479208/2811189)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation and link to the documentation. Although I've been trying to wade through the documentation, I tend to get lost between all the different places where documentation on the same topic can be found. Thank you for helping me to find the needle in the haystack!